# Oracle index not used with SQLAlchemy prepared statements

Tags: python, oracle, indexing, sqlalchemy, prepared-statement

I use Python and SQLAlchemy to access an Oracle 11 database.
As far as I think, SQLAlchemy always use prepared statements.

On a huge table (4 millions records), correctly indexed, SQLAlchemy filters queries doesn't use the index, so doing a full table scan is very slow ; using the same SQL code in a "raw" SQL editor (SQLplus) make Oracle use the index with good performances.

We tried to add "+index" hints on requests, without effect on Oracle execution path which still doesn't want to use the index.

Any idea ? Is it possible to really force Oracle to use an index, or to make SQLAlchemy to not use prepared statements ??

Best regards,
Thierry

Comment: Prepared statements can make things complicated for a few reasons.  It may be helpful to find the prepared statement as Oracle sees it.  Search for it with a query like: `select * from v$sql where lower(sql_fulltext) like '%something unique in your query%';`.  You may find there is a function on the bind variable, preventing indexes.  At the very least it will give you the SQL_ID.  When you have the SQL_ID, run this and paste the entire results in your question: `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(sql_id => 'sql_id from query'));`

Comment: Just for information, from an Oracle perspective, it is possible to force oracle to use index by the index hint
Syntax:
 select /*+ index(a,index_name) */ 
    a.* from table a;